# Why am I getting Invalid column name on field names that don't exist in my model?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, dbcontext, fluent

I am querying an entity with EF 5.0 Code First / DbContext. I am getting the following errors:

Invalid column name 'RetainedEarningsAccount_Key'.
Invalid column name 'PLSummaryAccount_Key'.

However, neither of these fields exist in the model. I assume some default configuration/mapping is happening here, but I don't know what it is. Here is the model class in question:

```
public GLEntity()
    {
        this.AccessEntities = new HashSet<AccessEntity>();
        this.BankAccountGLAccounts = new HashSet<BankAccountGLAccount>();
        this.BatchRestrictionEntities = new HashSet<BatchRestrictionEntity>();
        this.BudgetVersions = new HashSet<BudgetVersion>();
        this.CalendarCrossRefs = new HashSet<CalendarCrossRef>();
        this.ConsolDetails = new HashSet<ConsolDetail>();
        this.ConsolHeaders = new HashSet<ConsolHeader>();
        this.DefaultBudgetVersions = new HashSet<DefaultBudgetVersion>();
        this.Departments = new HashSet<Department>();
        this.ExpenseCodeDetails = new HashSet<ExpenseCodeDetail>();
        this.GLAccounts = new HashSet<GLAccount>();
        this.Journals = new HashSet<Journal>();
        this.PostingRules = new HashSet<PostingRule>();
        this.Processes = new HashSet<Process>();
        this.Properties = new HashSet<Property>();
        this.RecurringJournals = new HashSet<RecurringJournal>();
        this.RecurringTransactionGLs = new HashSet<RecurringTransactionGL>();
        this.EntitiesAlternate = new HashSet<GLEntity>();
        this.GLIntercompaniesDestinationEntities = new HashSet<GLIntercompany>();
        this.GLIntercompaniesSourceEntities = new HashSet<GLIntercompany>();
        this.TransGLs = new HashSet<TransGL>();
    }

    public System.Guid Key { get; set; }
    public string EntityID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> CurrentFiscalYear { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> CurrentPrd { get; set; }
    public string EntityType { get; set; }
    public string AllowPostingYN { get; set; }
    public string NextJournal { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> CompanyKey { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> RetainedEarningsAcctKey { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> PLSummaryAcctKey { get; set; }
    public string AccountingType { get; set; }
    public string UserCreated { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public string UserEdited { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Edited { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> AlternateEntityKey { get; set; }
    public string TrackJobs { get; set; }
    public string TrackUnits { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AccessEntity> AccessEntities { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BankAccountGLAccount> BankAccountGLAccounts { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BatchRestrictionEntity> BatchRestrictionEntities { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BudgetVersion> BudgetVersions { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CalendarCrossRef> CalendarCrossRefs { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ConsolDetail> ConsolDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ConsolHeader> ConsolHeaders { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DefaultBudgetVersion> DefaultBudgetVersions { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ExpenseCodeDetail> ExpenseCodeDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GLAccount> GLAccounts { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Journal> Journals { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PostingRule> PostingRules { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Process> Processes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Property> Properties { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RecurringJournal> RecurringJournals { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RecurringTransactionGL> RecurringTransactionGLs { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GLEntity> EntitiesAlternate { get; set; }
    public virtual GLEntity EntityAlternate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GLIntercompany> GLIntercompaniesDestinationEntities { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GLIntercompany> GLIntercompaniesSourceEntities { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TransGL> TransGLs { get; set; }
    public virtual GLAccount RetainedEarningsAccount { get; set; }
    public virtual GLAccount PLSummaryAccount { get; set; }

}
```

And here is the mapping:

```
public GLEntity_Mapping()
    {                        
          this.HasKey(t => t.Key);        
          this.ToTable("tblEntity");
          this.Property(t => t.Key).HasColumnName("KeyGUID");
          this.Property(t => t.EntityID).HasColumnName("EntityID").IsUnicode(false).HasMaxLength(10);
          this.Property(t => t.Description).HasColumnName("Description").IsUnicode(false).HasMaxLength(50);
          this.Property(t => t.CurrentFiscalYear).HasColumnName("CurrentFiscalYear");
          this.Property(t => t.CurrentPrd).HasColumnName("CurrentPrd");
          this.Property(t => t.EntityType).HasColumnName("EntityType").IsUnicode(false).IsFixedLength().HasMaxLength(1);
          this.Property(t => t.AllowPostingYN).HasColumnName("AllowPostingYN").IsUnicode(false).IsFixedLength().HasMaxLength(1);
          this.Property(t => t.NextJournal).HasColumnName("NextJournal").IsUnicode(false).HasMaxLength(20);
          this.Property(t => t.CompanyKey).HasColumnName("Company");
          this.Property(t => t.RetainedEarningsAcctKey).HasColumnName("RetainedEarningsAcct");
          this.Property(t => t.PLSummaryAcctKey).HasColumnName("PLSummaryAcct");
          this.Property(t => t.AccountingType).HasColumnName("AccountingType").IsUnicode(false).IsFixedLength().HasMaxLength(1);
          this.Property(t => t.UserCreated).HasColumnName("UserCreated").IsRequired().IsUnicode(false).HasMaxLength(50);
          this.Property(t => t.Created).HasColumnName("Created");
          this.Property(t => t.UserEdited).HasColumnName("UserEdited").IsUnicode(false).HasMaxLength(50);
          this.Property(t => t.Edited).HasColumnName("Edited");
          this.Property(t => t.AlternateEntityKey).HasColumnName("AlternateEntity");
          this.Property(t => t.TrackJobs).HasColumnName("TrackJobs").IsUnicode(false).IsFixedLength().HasMaxLength(1);
          this.Property(t => t.TrackUnits).HasColumnName("TrackUnits").IsUnicode(false).IsFixedLength().HasMaxLength(1);
          this.HasOptional(t => t.Company).WithMany(t => t.Entities).HasForeignKey(d => d.CompanyKey);
          this.HasOptional(t => t.EntityAlternate).WithMany(t => t.EntitiesAlternate).HasForeignKey(d => d.AlternateEntityKey);
     }
```

Why am I getting an error on non-existent properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the abbreviation `Acct` instead of `Account` in these properties...

```
public Nullable<System.Guid> RetainedEarningsAcctKey { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.Guid> PLSummaryAcctKey { get; set; }
```

...EF conventions do not recognize the properties as foreign keys for

```
public virtual GLAccount RetainedEarningsAccount { get; set; }
public virtual GLAccount PLSummaryAccount { get; set; }
```

You can either rename the FK properties to `RetainedEarningsAccountKey` and `PLSummaryAccountKey`. EF should recognize them correctly then according to the rule "*FK property name = Navigation property name + primary key name of target entity*".

Or define the properties as FKs with Fluent API in your `GLEntity_Mapping`:

```
this.HasOptional(t => t.RetainedEarningsAccount)
    .WithMany(a => a.SomeInverseCollection1)
    .HasForeignKey(t => t.RetainedEarningsAcctKey);

this.HasOptional(t => t.PLSummaryAccount)
    .WithMany(a => a.SomeInverseCollection2)
    .HasForeignKey(t => t.PLSummaryAcctKey);
```

`SomeInverseCollection1/2` are the related collections in `GLAccount` or use `WithMany()` without lambda parameter if there are no inverse collections in that class.

Comment: Thanks. Seems that tool I used to generate fluid mappings from my EDMX just isn't correct and misses this issue in numerous places.